# improve mysql select query with order by option

Tags: mysql

I have following table with around 10 million records.
and using following query to retrieve data, but it is taking more than 4, 5 seconds to hand over the response.

Is any way to improve query...?

```
CREATE TABLE `master` (
      `organizationName` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `organizationNameQuery` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `organizationLinkedinHandle` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `organizationDomain` varchar(110) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `source` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          UNIQUE KEY `master_inx` (`organizationName`(80),`organizationDomain`(80),`organizationLinkedinHandle`(80),`organizationNameQuery`(80),`source`),
          KEY `organizationDomain` (`organizationDomain`),
          KEY `domainWithModified` (`organizationDomain`,`modified`),
          KEY `modifiedInx` (`modified`)
        );
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM Organizations.master 
      where ( ( organizationDomain like 'linkedin.com' 
                || organizationNameQuery = 'linkedin.com') 
              and source like 'MY_SOURCE') ) M 
ORDER BY M.modified DESC limit 1;
```

1 row in set (4.69 sec)

**UPDATE**

I found by breaking **OR** operator i am getting result faster.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM Organizations.master 
      where ( ( organizationDomain like 'linkedin.com') 
              and source like 'MY_SOURCE') ) M 
ORDER BY M.modified DESC limit 1;
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

2. 

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM Organizations.master 
          where ( (organizationNameQuery = 'linkedin.com') 
                  and source like 'MY_SOURCE') ) M 
    ORDER BY M.modified DESC limit 1;
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: No point using like for exact comparisions..and I don't like || when or is clearer.

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you about this? Also, could you store data like the domain in normalized form?

Comment: `organizationName`,organizationNameQuery , `organizationLinkedinHandle`? I don't see these in the table? Though 5 secs for 10m isn't bad

Comment: this table contain 35 columns i only put most relevant

Comment: will it make sense adding index organizationNameQuery as part of OR ?

Comment: `organizationName` appears in your query and the others appear in `master_inx`so I would say they are relevant..Also is there an auto_increment primary key ?

Comment: no @P.Salmon, it is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR`, not `||` in that context.

The performance villain is `OR`.  Turn the `OR` into `UNION`:

```
( SELECT * 
    FROM Organizations.master 
    WHERE organizationDomain = 'linkedin.com' 
      AND source = 'MY_SOURCE'
    ORDER BY modified DESC limit 1
) UNION ALL
( SELECT * 
    FROM Organizations.master 
    WHERE organizationNameQuery = 'linkedin.com' 
      AND source = 'MY_SOURCE'
    ORDER BY modified DESC limit 1
}
ORDER BY modified DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Notes:

- This formulation is likely to take about 0.00s to run.
- The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` shows up 3 times.
- If you need `OFFSET`, things get a little tricky.
- Change back to `LIKE` if you allow users to enter wildcards.
- A leading wildcard would not be efficient.
- `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION` (aka `UNION DISTINCT`).
- It needs two new composite indexes; the order of the 2 columns is not critical:

  ```
  INDEX(organizationDomain, source),
  INDEX(organizationNameQuery, source)
  ```

Answer (score -1):

As I checked the query I think you can remove the like operator and use =.

```
SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT * FROM Organizations.master
                where ( (organizationDomain = 'linkedin.com' ||
                         organizationNameQuery = 'linkedin.com') 
                  and source = 'MY_SOURCE') 
              ) M
       ORDER BY M.modified DESC limit 1
```

Comment: The effect, even when detected, will be close to zero.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase i have added more details

Comment: `LIKE` _without any wild cards_ is optimized the same as `=`.